# Stop validation error item from being published

Tags: validation, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

We are using Sitecore 7.2 and have implemented the 'Required' field validator for number of fields.

However, the user can still save or create an item with validation error.

I know that we can stop this validation errored items from being published using Work Flow.

We do not want to implement any workflow, therefore can someone please suggest how to stop validation errored item from being able to published?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own validation class like this (the one below only check for **validation bar** errors):

```cs
public void ValidateItem(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ItemProcessingEventArgs theArgs = (ItemProcessingEventArgs) args;
    Item currentItem = theArgs.Context.PublishHelper.GetSourceItem(theArgs.Context.ItemId);
    if ((currentItem != null) && (currentItem.Paths.IsContentItem))
    {
        if (!IsItemValid(currentItem))
        {
            theArgs.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}

private static bool IsItemValid(Item item)
{
    item.Fields.ReadAll();
    ValidatorCollection validators = ValidatorManager.GetFieldsValidators(
        ValidatorsMode.ValidatorBar, item.Fields.Select(f => new FieldDescriptor(item, f.Name)), item.Database);
    var options = new ValidatorOptions(true);
    ValidatorManager.Validate(validators, options);
    foreach (BaseValidator validator in validators)
    {
        if (validator.Result != ValidatorResult.Valid)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and add event handler to `publish:itemProcessing` event:

```xml
<event name="publish:itemProcessing" help="Receives an argument of type ItemProcessingEventArgs (namespace: Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem)">
    <handler type="My.Assembly.Namespace.ValidateBeforePublish, My.Assembly" method="ValidateItem"/>
</event>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the parameters field on the validation to "Result=FatalError" to stop the user from saving an item before the issue is resolved.  This way the user has to fix the issue before they are allowed to save.